# Spring AMQP to Spring Cloud Stream migration - existing queue

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to add Spring Cloud Stream to the existing project that uses Spring AMQP with RabbitMQ.

I have the following rabbit configuration:

Producer exchange name: `producer.mail-sent.exchange`

Consumer queue name: `consumer.mail-sent.queue`

On the producer's side I configure like this:

`spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        output:
          contentType: application/json
          destination: producer.mail-sent.exchange`

And using the following code:

```
@Autowired
private Source source;
...
source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(someStuff).build());
...
```

On the consumer's side I have the following config:

`spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          contentType: application/json
          destination: producer.mail-sent.exchange
          group: consumer.mail-sent.queue`

With the following code:

```
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
...
@StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
public void handle(String someStuff) {
    log.info("some stuff is received: " + someStuff);
}
```

And it seems that it works. :)
But! On the rabbit's side I have a new queue named `producer.mail-sent.exchange.consumer.mail-sent.queue`, but I want it to use the existing queue named `consumer.mail-sent.queue`.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently supported; while many properties are configurable (routing key etc), the queue name is always `<destination>.<group>`.

If you want to consume from an existing application, consider using a `@RabbitListner` instead of a `@StreamListener`.

Feel free to open a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/issues) referencing this post - many other "opinionated" configuration settings (such as routing key) are configurable, but not the queue name itself. Perhaps we could add a boolean `includeDestInQueueName`. Reference this question in the issue.

Comment: Ok :) Thanks for quick response!

Comment: We are also facing same issue.We have existing rabbitmq cluster  and would like to create a consumer client for existing cluster (fanout).Are you suggesting to not to use Spring cloud stream for existing rabbitmq clusters ? we are planning to create generic client using cloud stream as next year we have to move to Kinesis .

Comment: It won't be hard to add support for complete custom naming for the queue; it's just not there today; as I suggested to the OP, opening a GitHub issue to request the enhancement is the first step. You can start with a `@RabbitListener` and switch it to `@StreamListener` when the capability is available. He opened [this issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/issues/93). Add your voice to increase priority.